# Proxy with custom subproxy routing

Tags: osx

I'm using a lot of networks with over 15 different proxy servers to access various resources. In typical usage PAC file comes in picture to make browser go to one or another proxy.
However, for non-browser tools like docker, curl, etc - there's a need in directly stating the proxy to use, as they don't work with PAC file. The problem is that all the tools I use need to use a set of 4-5 different proxy servers. Since they're compiled and/or proprietary applications, I don't have a direct way to manually go change the codebase to utilize one or another URL. However, they respect HTTP_PROXY variables, so I could utilize my own proxy. I'm trying to plug proxy in between that would specifically chose the route to go with, but none of the available on the internet proxy servers have a support of specific set of rules like PAC file does. I don't have admin on machine where it's happening, so iptables is also out of picture.

Is there a solution for my problem? How to get this done?
client -> my_proxy -> proxy_1 -> Google.com.
client -> my_proxy -> proxy_2 -> yahoo.com.
client -> my_proxy -> proxy_3 -> Amazon.com.
And so on. I have list of rules available, but I can't find application to achieve this task.